# Convert pdf into images using C# - Ghostscript

Tags: c#, pdf, unity-game-engine, png, ghostscript

I need to convert pdf-files into images with a script in C# for Unity. Ghostscript shouldn't be installed on disk to do this. I tried to include the ghostscript .dll and use it with a wrapper which uses the following functions:

```
gsapi_new_instance
gsapi_init_with_args
gsapi_exit
gsapi_delete_instance
```

However, if I use the commands `-sDEVICE=png16m -sOutputFile=outputpath.png inputpath.pdf` as arguments, it is not working. The first page of the pdf file is created but the others are not. I used "-%d" in the outputpath, but it's not working either. e.g. C:\Example-%d.png

I am using Ghostscript version 9.16, Unity version 5.2.0f3 and Visual Studio 2015.

Can please anyone tell me, why the first image file is created and the others are not? Is there any simple alternative for using ghostscript to create multiple images from a pdf by using C#?

Comment: There's Ghostscript Sharp and Ghostscript.NET, neither are maintained by Artifex but by open source contributors. You don't specify which version of GS you are using but I would suggest that the reason you have a problem is because you have not specified -dNOPAUSE so GS is waiting for a keypress between pages. If you look at stdout you will probably see it asking for you to press return.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast answer. I am using version 9.16. I tested the application with -dNOPAUSE but it's still not working.

Comment: You probably need to look at the back channel output on stderr and stdout to see what is going on. Does the first page filename contain a numeric ? If not then you don't have the syntax correct for the output filename.

Comment: Yes, the first page contains a numeric.

Comment: Well, can't see why there would be a problem then, what does teh back channel contain ?

Comment: So, I tested it now in the console and there it works fine. All pages are created with the appropriate number. I used the same commands as in my script. However, my script doesn't work either. The first page is created and the others not. Now, there can only be a mistake in the wrapper script. I will search for that, otherwise I will try other wrappers like Victor and Nomada have suggested. Thanks for your help.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to KenS and all the others.

My problem was that I defined -dNOPAUSE as my first argument. However, the first argument shouldn't be defined for ghostscript. It is not realized from ghostscript, so that's why I got only the first page. Thanks to KenS suggestion with -dNOPAUSE, I was able to find the error.

I hope this helps others, too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Magick.Net](https://magick.codeplex.com/) ?

It's a very popular .NET wrapper for the ImageMagick library
(It uses Ghostscript under the hood for pdfs)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast answer. I will try it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

First install NuGet `Install-Package GhostScriptSharp`.
Then you could do something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convertetion PDF to image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Path">Path to file for convertetion</param>
/// <param name="PDFfile">Book name on HDD</param>
/// <param name="Devise">Select one of the formats, jpg</param>
/// <param name="PageFormat">Select one of page formats, like A4</param>
/// <param name="qualityX"> Select quality, 200X200 ~ 1200X1900</param>
/// <param name="qualityY">Select quality, 200X200 ~ 1200X1900</param>
    public void CreatPDF(string Path, string PDFfile, GhostscriptSharp.Settings.GhostscriptDevices Devise,
GhostscriptSharp.Settings.GhostscriptPageSizes PageFormat, int qualityX, int qualityY)
    {
        GhostscriptSharp.GhostscriptSettings SettingsForConvert = new GhostscriptSharp.GhostscriptSettings();

        SettingsForConvert.Device = Devise;

        GhostscriptSharp.Settings.GhostscriptPageSize pageSize = new GhostscriptSharp.Settings.GhostscriptPageSize();
        pageSize.Native = PageFormat;
        SettingsForConvert.Size = pageSize;

        SettingsForConvert.Resolution = new System.Drawing.Size(qualityX, qualityY);

        GhostscriptSharp.GhostscriptWrapper.GenerateOutput(Path, @"C:\" + PDFfile + "\\" + PDFfile + "_" + "%d.jpg", SettingsForConvert); // here you could set path and name for out put file.
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast answer! I will try that out!

Comment: If I try to install the package in Visual Studio 2015, I get the following error message: `install-package : Could not install package 'Ghostscript.NET 1.2.0'. You are 
trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework.` Sorry for that stupid question, but any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: You can get it here https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/611369 and then add to your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I added the Ghostscript.NET.dll to my project references. How can I use GhostscriptSharp like in your code?

Comment: Okay, I fixed my answer. Look on it. This is working like that I checked that in visual studio 12. Package working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I try to install package, I get the same error message as before with Ghostscript.NET 1.2.0. I installed GhostscriptSharp from here: https://github.com/mephraim/ghostscriptsharp. After that, I added the scripts into my solution. But, I can't get it working. I updated my question, because I am using the game engine Unity. Sorry for that. This game engine doesn't support System.Drawing. The error message says: `The type or namespace name Drawing does not exist in the namespace System. Are you missing an assembly reference?` Do you know what alternative way I can do?

Comment: GhostscriptSharp.GhostscriptSettings.Resolution is System.Drawing.Size structure. You could try to remove this lineSettingsForConvert.Resolution = new System.Drawing.Size(qualityX, qualityY); . You should get the same dpi that it was in original pdf file.

Comment: The problem is that I have to remove all lines in GhostscriptSharp that contains System.Drawing as well, because Unity can't recognize them. If I do that, I get this error message `ExternalException: Ghostscript conversion error`